# PHP invalid hash tiger192 3

Tags: php

I am using a php code with php 5.4 and i am trying to hash a string with tiger192,3. I am not getting a correct hash after all..

```
$keyLength = 24;
$keyCharacters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$string = '';
$key = '';
$keyHash = '';
$first8Hash = '';
$uniqueKey = false;

while ($uniqueKey == false)
{
    for ($p = 0; $p < $keyLength; $p++)
    {
        $string .= $keyCharacters[mt_rand(0, strlen($keyCharacters)-1)];
    }

    $key = $string;
    $keyHash = hash('tiger192,3', $key);
    $first8Hash = substr($keyHash, 0, 16);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `penkeys` WHERE first8 = '" . $first8Hash . "'";
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
    while ($keyrow = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
    {
        $uniqueKey = false;
    }
    $db->sql_freeresult($result);       
    $uniqueKey = true;
}
```

I am hashing the string `nQ5GcLMsOlPIaUYJOMkmjo7f`
I should be getting `babcb7d489332aee9c554a7a654bb65b4dd892e5b80e0156` but i am getting `ee2a3389d4b7bcba5bb64b657a4a559c56010eb8e592d84d`.
Can you help me?

Comment: How do you know `babcb7d489332aee9c554a7a654bb65b4dd892e5b80e0156` is the correct result of tiger192,3?

Comment: I checked through many websites of tiger encryption like http://www.timestampgenerator.com/tools/tiger192,3-generator/

Comment: interesting, it does indeed. I checked here - https://md5hashing.net/hash/tiger192%2C3 - and got the php result. Now the fun part is figuring out why.

Comment: That's the problem lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting case where both answers (both the php answer and the timestampgenerator answer) are correct. In PHP >= 5.4, the tiger hashes use big-endian byte notation and in PHP < 5.4, it presumably used little-endian byte notation (noted in the changelog http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php). The function below is in the php docs and `oldtiger` gives `babcb7d489332aee9c554a7a654bb65b4dd892e5b80e0156` as the result.

```
function old_tiger($data = "", $width=192, $rounds = 3) {
return substr(
    implode(
        array_map(
            function ($h) {
                return str_pad(bin2hex(strrev($h)), 16, "0");
            },
            str_split(hash("tiger192,$rounds", $data, true), 8)
        )
    ),
    0, 48-(192-$width)/4
);
}
echo hash('tiger192,3', 'a-string'), PHP_EOL;
echo old_tiger('a-string'), PHP_EOL;
```

If you notice, both `babcb7d489332aee9c554a7a654bb65b4dd892e5b80e0156` and `ee2a3389d4b7bcba5bb64b657a4a559c56010eb8e592d84d` are anagrams of each other which is more than a coincidence. The endianness is changed between the two strings. Each set of 8 bytes is in byte-reversed order.

`ee`-`2a`-`33`-`89`-`d4`-`b7`-`bc`-`ba` becomes `ba`-`bc`-`b7`-`d4`-`89`-`33`-`2a`-`ee`. The byte-order endieness is switched for each 64-bit(8 byte) word.